# Fullcalendar ayuda con slotDuration

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, fullcalendar

Queria consultar sobre fullcalendar. Estoy haciendo una agenda de turnos. Lo que necesito es que dependiendo de la agenda de cada medico, en eso estaria la franja horaria y la duracion de cada turno, (tiempo que dura la consulta) este dividida la 'timeGridWeek'..

Dentro de la BD tengo datos sobre la franja horaria y la duracion del turno. Lo que yo queria es que al definir el calendar..

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      //llamar a una funcion que devuelva lo de la agenda del profesional

      buscarAgenda();
    
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid', 'interaction', 'list' ],

        defaultView:'timeGridWeek',

        header:{

            left: 'prev,next today miBoton',

            center: 'title',

            right:'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'

        },
         
        slotDuration:"00:15:00",

        minTime:"08:00:00",

        maxTime:"20:00:00",

        allDaySlot: false,

        slotLabelInterval : '00:15:00',

        slotLabelFormat: function (date){

          return date.date.hour.toString().padStart(2, '0') +':'+ date.date.minute.toString().padStart(2,'0');

        }

});
```

Lo que queria en esta deficion era poner una variable en donde dice

```
slotDuration:"00:15:00"
```

Se podra?. Quizas es una pregunta obvia pero no se me ocurrio como solucionarlo.

Al llamado de los valores lo hago con ajax, type POST.. los valores los recibo y los puedo poner en un input o algo, pero no se como meter los valores dentro de la definicion..

Desde ya muchas gracias y espero que se haya entendido el problema..

Agrego el codigo de la funcion de donde obtengo los datos.

```
    function buscarAgenda(){
  console.log("buscarAgenda");
  var action = 'buscarAgenda';
  $.ajax({
      url : 'selectAgendaProf.php',
      type : 'POST',
      async : true,
      data : {action : action},

      success: function(r){
        if(r != 'error'){
          var info = JSON.parse(r);
          var slotDuration = info.duracionAProf;
          $('#slotDuracion').val(slotDuration);
        }
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: Claro que se puede, ya sea creando el javascript en php o usando Ajax mandar a pedir la informacion que necesitas.

Comment: gracias por responder @alanfcm pero lo que quiero hacer es en vez de poner una constante "00:15:00" por una variable.. yo al valor que necesito lo traigo mediante ajax y PHP desde la BD.. El problema es que me da errores cuando pongo esa variable en la definicion.

Comment: Podrias mostrar como traes el valor y como estas intentando ponerlo?

Comment: @alanfcm
    function buscarAgenda(){
      var action = 'buscarAgenda';
      $.ajax({
          url : 'selectAgendaProf.php',
          type : 'POST',
          async : true,
          data : {action : action},
          success: function(r){
            if(r != 'error'){
              var info = JSON.parse(r);
              var slotDuration = info.duracionAProf;
              $('#slotDuracion').val(slotDuration);
            }
          }
        });

      }

Comment: el valor llega y trato de ponerlo en la variable esa. pero no se como..

Comment: Agrega el codigo editando tu pregunta,

Comment: @alanfcm ahi la edite..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente mueve la definicion del Fullcalendar dentro de la funcion.  Algo asi:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
  //llamar a una funcion que devuelva lo de la agenda del profesional

  buscarAgenda();
});

function buscarAgenda(){
  console.log("buscarAgenda");
  var action = 'buscarAgenda';
  $.ajax({
      url : 'selectAgendaProf.php',
      type : 'POST',
      async : true,
      data : {action : action},

      success: function(r){
        if(r != 'error'){
          var info = JSON.parse(r);
          var slotDuration = info.duracionAProf;
          var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

    plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid', 'interaction', 'list' ],

    defaultView:'timeGridWeek',

    header:{

        left: 'prev,next today miBoton',

        center: 'title',

        right:'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'

    },
     
    slotDuration: slotDuration,

    minTime:"08:00:00",

    maxTime:"20:00:00",

    allDaySlot: false,

    slotLabelInterval : '00:15:00',

    slotLabelFormat: function (date){

      return date.date.hour.toString().padStart(2, '0') +':'+ date.date.minute.toString().padStart(2,'0');

    }
        }
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: Excelente @alanfcm muchisimas gracias!.