# Fullcalendar problema con actualizar eventos

Tags: javascript, funciones, eventos, fullcalendar

Tengo un problema.. No lo puedo resolver de la forma normal. Que seria utilizando las funciones que brinda `fullCalendar."refetchEvents"`...

Me muestra el error:

> TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Dejo el código y un link:

[Fullcalendar ayuda con slotDuration](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392062/fullcalendar-ayuda-con-slotduration) (con esto me ayudaron a que se cargaran correctamente los eventos)

Función en .js que agrega un evento a la base de datos, lo hace correctamente:

```
        $('#btnReservarTurno').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $('#horaInicio').html();
        var fechaTurno = $('#reservaDate').val();
        var expDataInici = moment(fechaTurno, "DD/MM/YYYY");
        var start = $('#horaInicio option:selected').val();  
        var end = $('#horaFin option:selected').val();  
        var action = "reservarTurno";
        $.ajax({
            url : 'guardarTurno.php',
            type : 'POST',
            async : true,
            data: {action : action, title : title, descripcionTurno : descripcionTurno, start : start, end : end, textColor : textColor, backgroundColor : backgroundColor, idPaciente : idPaciente, idProf : idProf, idServicio : idServicio, idEstado : idEstado, idSesion : idSesion, idPagoServicio : idPagoServicio, idHC : idHC,fechaTurno:fechaTurno},

            success : function(r){
                 if(r != 'error'){
                    alertify.success("Excelente!. Venta realizada con exito!.");
                    $("#modalMenuReserva").modal("hide");           
                 }else{
                    alertify.error("Ups!. Hubo un problema..");
                 }
            },
            error : function(error) {
            }
        })
    });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
buscarAgenda();
});


    function buscarAgenda(){
    var action = 'buscarAgenda';
    $.ajax({
        url : 'selectAgendaProf.php',
        type : 'POST',
        async : true,
        data : {action : action},
        success: function(r){
            if(r != 'error'){
                var info = JSON.parse(r);
                var slotDuration = info.duracionAProf;
                $('#slotDuracion').val(slotDuration);
                var minTime = info.horaInic1;
                if(info.horaFinal2 != ""){
                    var maxTime = info.horaFinal2;          
                }else{
                    var maxTime = info.horaFinal1;          
                }
                var minTimeBuss = minTime.substring(0,5);
                var maxTimeBuss = maxTime.substring(0,5);
                $('#minTime').val(minTimeBuss);
                $('#maxTime').val(maxTimeBuss);
                var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid', 'interaction', 'list' ],
                    defaultView:'timeGridWeek',
                    header:{
                        left: 'prev,next today miBoton',
                        center: 'title',
                        right:'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                    },
                    slotDuration: slotDuration,
                    minTime: minTime,
                    maxTime: maxTime,
                    allDaySlot: false,
                    slotLabelInterval : slotDuration,
                    slotLabelFormat: function (date){
                        return date.date.hour.toString().padStart(2, '0') +':'+ date.date.minute.toString().padStart(2,'0');
                    },
                    dateClick:function(info){
                        $("#fecha").val(info.dateStr);
                        dateStr = info.dateStr;
                        dateObj = new Date(dateStr); /* Or empty, for today */
                        dateIntNTZ = dateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
                        dateObjNTZ = new Date(dateIntNTZ);
                        dateObjNTZ.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                        $("#modalMenuReserva").modal();
                        cargarProf();
                        selectPaciente();
                        selectPrestador();
                        selectTratamiento();
                        cargarHoras1(dateObjNTZ.toISOString().slice(0, 10)); 
                        fechaNueva = dateObjNTZ.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                        arrayFecha = fechaNueva.split('-');
                        fechaFinal = arrayFecha[2] + '-' + arrayFecha[1] + '-' + arrayFecha[0];
                        $("#reservaDate").val(fechaFinal);
                    },            
                    events:'http://localhost:81/hardturn/vista/listarTurnos.php'
                });
                calendar.setOption('locale','Es');
                calendar.render();
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Todas las funciones están dentro de la función "*buscarAgenda*".

Lo único raro es que, al ir para adelante y para atrás en la agenda, se actualizan los eventos.

Espero se entienda la pregunta y el error. Gracias!

Comment: En ese código no hay un `refetchEvents`. ¿Cuál es la línea que genera el error?

Comment: @Triby no hay porque no funciona. En el success despues de cerrar el modal. Lo quise colocar pero me genera el error 
    TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
La solucion, poco elegante, fue de ir para atras y volver adelante. En el calendario digo.
            $(".fc-next-button").trigger("click");
            $(".fc-prev-button").trigger("click");